# Providers,ChangeDetection,Encapsulations,host in Angular component definitions

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I see some packages where they give **providers**, **encapsulations**, **changeDetections**, **host** as the following piece of code. What do they mean and how does it behave in the component class with respect to the following code.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ng-select',
    templateUrl: './ng-select.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./ng-select.component.scss'],
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => NgSelectComponent),
        multi: true
    }],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    host: {
        'role': 'listbox',
        'class': 'ng-select',
        '[class.ng-select-single]': '!multiple',
    }
})
```

Comment: Providers: https://angular.io/guide/providers
View Encapsulation: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html
Host Binding: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/custom-directives/hostlistener-and-hostbinding/
Change Detection: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Answer (score 2):

It Means following things

- encapsulation if you use ViewEncapsulation.None, it means that styles you will write either styles attribute or styleUrl:(css file), will be global scope, so if you have

  .danger{
  color:red
  }
  you can use that style also outside component
- host means that you are adding properties on host element itself, for example on this case, it will add next properties

  ng-select role class="ng-select"\
- providers means that the services that you inject there, will be available on the component level only, and if you have two different ng-select they both will have different instances of this class
- change detection you can configure how change detection works on this component, by default on every change detection cycle it will run also this component, OnPush strategy means that it will run change detection on this component only if, any of input property references has been changed

Comment: What does host do bro? does it acts like adding an attribute to the template?

Comment: yes you can manipulate host component, from there <ng-select role class="ng-select"> </ng-select> this will be the case